# Cant get a Docker image with apache to display the test webpage

Tags: apache, docker

I have a docker image where I have put apache.  I want it to that when the container starts, apache starts and I can visit the test page.  However, the page is not appearing when I try.

This is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER me <me@me.com>
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y httpd php
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I am running the container with the command `docker run -d -P <container_name>`, and when I do `docker ps`, I see the ports section being populated correctly, with `0.0.0.0:32784->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->443/tcp` as the output.

The url im trying to use to access it is 172.17.0.2:32784.

Any ideas?

Comment: The test page is probably being served on port 32784 (instead of port 80), if you haven't tried it already.

Comment: The url im trying to use to access it is 172.17.0.2:32784, so thats unfortunately not the issue

Comment: Are you running the container via docker-machine (boot2docker)? 172.17.0.2 is the private address of your machine?

Comment: Why are there two CMD?

Comment: When I do `docker inspect` on the container, the values that are returned are `"Gateway": "172.17.0.1", "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`.  I dont see any other IP's on there that could be a different address.

Comment: Also, I provisioned a VM from amazon in order to run it on a Redhat box.  Ive already opened the ports inside of the AWS security group.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that I was trying to connect with the docker containers IP, when the IP I shouldve been connecting with the IP of the server that it was hosted on.

Comment: Yes, if it is on AWS, then you will need to connect to the elastic IP of your VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was trying to connect with the docker containers IP, when the IP I shouldve been connecting with the IP of the server that it was hosted on.

Derp.